# Postman. How get all endpoints in web api asp.net core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, postman

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/build-web-api-aspnet-core/3-exercise-create-web-api) says that using the **ls** command of the **httprepl** tool, you can list all available endpoints web api asp.net core. Is it possible to do something similar in **Postman**?

Comment: I doubt the framework would expose this information *to clients* by default.  Most likely you'd need to create an endpoint which provides this information and query that endpoint.  Alternatively, you can use tools like Swagger to generate API documentation which can be examined in your web browser.

Comment: Thank you. That is, without this, **httprepl** can get the list, but the **Postman** cannot? Did I get it right?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something about this tool, that would be my expectation.  A command-line tool can examine the source code and the compiled binaries, but a *client-side* tool has only HTTP requests/responses available to it.

Comment: Looks like httprepl is a swagger client? Which would require the web server to export a swagger json definition. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/aspnet/core/web-api/http-repl/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows#manually-point-to-the-openapi-description-for-the-web-api

Comment: @David Seems that httprepl falls into the client-side tool definition, as it [appears to use an Open API spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/http-repl/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows#manually-point-to-the-openapi-description-for-the-web-api) to discover info about the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can import Swagger APIs Into Postman Collection, and list the API endpoints.

This is my swagger UI which is running on localhost:

[image]

The `https://localhost:7274/swagger/v1/swagger.json` file contains all endpoints.

In the postman, click the Import button, in the popup window, paste the swagger JSON document link.

[image]

After that, choose how to import the API and click the Import button.

[image]

Then, you can find all endpoints from the Collections.

[image]

And then, click your api collection, and set the `baseUrl` variable, and click the Save button.

[image]

After that, click the endpoint and send request, it will successfully invoke the endpoint.

[image]